# Refreshing a Side Input in Apache Beam/Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was looking in to how to refresh a side input in a dataflow job without having to restart the pipeline.  I found this example https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/865 but I cannot seem to get it to work locally or deployed.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
 final PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> versionCoreMapping = 
         pipeline.apply("Read from spanner for active versions for different cores",

         SpannerIO.read()
                    .withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig)
                    .withInstanceId(options.getInstanceId())
                    .withDatabaseId(options.getDatabaseId())
                    .withQuery("SELECT version, sys, action FROM table"))
                .apply("Window Core Version Map",
                    Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))))
                .apply("Core Version Map into Global Window",
                    Window.into(new GlobalWindows()))
                .apply("Refresh Cache for Versioning", 
                       ParDo.of(new RefreshCache("sys", "version", "action")))
                .apply("convert to version table to map", View.asMap());
```

RefreshCache

```
public class RefreshCache extends DoFn<Struct, KV<String, String>> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
   private String key;
   private String value;
   private String secondaryPrimaryKey;
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RefreshCache.class);

public RefreshCache(String key, String value, String secondaryPrimaryKey) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.secondaryPrimaryKey = secondaryPrimaryKey;
}

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Refreshing cache..." + key);
        Struct row = c.element();
        KV<String, String> returnMap;
        if(null != secondaryPrimaryKey) {
            returnMap = KV.of(row.getString(key).concat(",").concat(row.getString(secondaryPrimaryKey)), row.getString(value));
        } else {
            returnMap = KV.of(row.getString(key), row.getString(value));
        }

        c.output(returnMap);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this I do not see the log inside of RefreshCache repeating at a 5 second interval.

Any help with this would be great

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: This is just a hunch and not sure if this might make a difference but could you add the following lines to your window triggering: `.apply(Window.into(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
           .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
           .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
           .discardingFiredPanes());`

Comment: This is just to ensure that you are not accumulating on your window panes

Comment: The added time delay is just so that it would be easier to view the diff between the windows